# jQuery waypoints not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-waypoints

[Example Page](http://dirtybirddesignlab.com/TLC/WebsiteV4A/index.php) works pretty much as desired in FF & Chrome but not in Safari. There are some position changes (from fixed to static back to fixed) but I'm not aware of any issues Safari has w/positioning (non mobile safari). Below is my code:

```
$(function(){
    var footerPos = function () {
        var w = $(window).height();
        var top = (w-110);
        $('footer').css('top', top);
    };
    $(document).ready(footerPos);
    $(window).resize(footerPos);
    $('footer').waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            $('footer').css({'position':'static'}).animate({'height':'600px', 'top':'auto'}, 400, footerPos) ;
            $('.tfContent').css({'height':'200px'});
            $('p.extra').fadeIn('fast');
            $('#arrow').addClass('arrowDown');
            console.log('down');
        } else if (direction === 'up') {
            $('.tfContent').css({'background':'white'});
            $('footer').css({'position':'fixed','top':footerPos});
            $('.tfContent').css({'height':'60px'});
            $('p.extra').slideUp('fast');
            $('#arrow').removeClass('arrowDown');
                console.log('up');
        }
        }, { offset: 'bottom-in-view' });
```

If you look in Chrome first, you will see when you scroll to the bottom of the page the white content ('.tfContent') expands down, the 'footer' changes from fixed to static position and increases it's height. But not in Safari. Any ideas?
ALSO: is there any way to make the page scroll to the bottom in the waypoints function? This, for some reason doesn't work

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height()}, 1400, "easeOutQuint");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your specific code, but in general using a `fixed` position element as the waypoint (`footer` here) is not going to work the way you expect. Waypoints works by looking at an element's scroll position in relation to the document, and fixed position elements are always changing in that regard.

Comment: I have two ideas to combat this, neither of which I can seem to implement correctly. Above the fixed position footer is a div #mid, if I could find the bottom of it, could I store it in a variable and use that as a waypoint? it is always 'in-view' so I don't think using 'bottom-in-view' will work here. Second idea is to create a relatively positioned div#shim and position it off the page or have its margin-bottom equal to it's height and use it... any good?

Comment: The first one can be achieved by using `offset: function() { return -$(this).outerHeight(); }`